# Tikz: failure to fill

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I've just gotten into the tikz package, and am using tikzpicture to do some work with graphs and complexes on them. I want to be able to fill in certain areas of the graphs. I've found what I want, but there is a thing that's bugging me (see the code and picture).

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzstyle{vertex}=[draw,circle, fill = black, inner sep = 1.5pt] 
  \node[vertex] (1) [label = right:$a$] at (0,0) {};
  \node[vertex] (2) [label = right:$b$] at (3,0) {};
  \node[vertex] (3) [label = right:$c$] at (1,1.5) {};
  \node[vertex] (4) [label = above:$d$] at (1,3) {};
  \node[vertex] (5) [label = below:$e$] at (0,-2) {};
  \node[vertex] (6) [label = below:$f$] at (2,-2) {};
  \draw[fill=gray] (3) to (4) to [out=180,in=90] (-1.5,0) to [out=-90,in=135] (5) to [out=90,in=-90] (-0.5,0) to [out=90,in=180] (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

At the edge cd, there is a strip that is not filled in, while I want it to be. Are there any suggestions or solutions to this problem? Have I missed something? Can I do anything differently? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I suppose, that you like to obtain the following picture:

[image]

From code below you can see, that the coordinates are determined by `.center`. Without this it is considered one of anchors on node's shape border. To be filled area under nodes, I also use `background library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

    \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzstyle{vertex}=[draw,circle, fill = black, inner sep = 1.5pt]
  \node[vertex] (1) [label = right:$a$] at (0,0) {};
  \node[vertex] (2) [label = right:$b$] at (3,0) {};
  \node[vertex] (3) [label = right:$c$] at (1,1.5) {};
  \node[vertex] (4) [label = above:$d$] at (1,3) {};
  \node[vertex] (5) [label = below:$e$] at (0,-2) {};
  \node[vertex] (6) [label = below:$f$] at (2,-2) {};
\scoped[on background layer]
  \draw[fill=gray] (3.center) to (4.center) to [out=180,in=90] (-1.5,0) to [out=-90,in=135] (5.center) to [out=90,in=-90] (-0.5,0) to [out=90,in=180] (3.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}

  \path coordinate["$a$"  right] (1)  at (0,0) 
        coordinate["$b$"  right] (2)  at (3,0) 
        coordinate["$c$"  right] (3)  at (1,1.5) 
        coordinate["$d$"  above] (4)  at (1,3) 
        coordinate["$e$"  below] (5)  at (0,-2) 
        coordinate["$f$"  below] (6)  at (2,-2) ;

  \draw[fill=gray] (3) to (4) 
                       to [out=180,in=90] (-1.5,0) 
                       to [out=-90,in=135] (5) 
                       to [out=90,in=-90] (-0.5,0) 
                       to [out=90,in=180] (3);

  \foreach \c in {1,...,6}{\fill (\c) circle (1.5 pt); }

\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]